# Reset Array in PL/SQL

Tags: arrays, arraylist, plsql

I declare an associate array like this

```
TYPE t_a_rec IS RECORD
(
a_id         NUMBER,
a_name       VARCHAR2 (500),
assigned          NUMBER:= 0
);



TYPE t_a IS TABLE OF t_a_rec
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   a   t_a;
```

and in a part of code i need to reset all the assigned values to zero. so my code is:

```
    IF flag = TRUE
     THEN
        FOR i IN a.FIRST .. a.LAST
        LOOP
           a(i).assigned := 0;
        END LOOP;
     END IF;
```

Is there any way to reset without loop?
In example something like:

```
   IF flag = TRUE
     THEN

           a(:).assigned := 0; or a(all).assigned := 0;

     END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of associative arrays You don't have any option other than looping throgh it to reset one value from Your arrays element. Please read through the [processing associative arrays in loops](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:173586000346213111). You are looping the arryas wrong. Please consider the commented code in this example.

```
declare
   type t_a_rec is record(
      a_id     number,
      a_name   varchar2(500),
      assigned number := 0);
   type t_a is table of t_a_rec index by pls_integer;
   a t_a;
   li_idx int;
begin
   a(1).a_id := 1;
   a(1).a_name := 'Test Name';
   a(1).assigned := 100;

   a(3).a_id := 2;
   a(3).a_name := 'Test Name 2';
   a(3).assigned := 200;

   /* for i in a.first .. a.last loop      
      dbms_output.put_line(a(i).assigned);
   end loop;*/

   li_idx := a.first;
   while (li_idx is not null) loop
      dbms_output.put_line(a(li_idx).assigned);
      li_idx := a.next(li_idx);
   end loop;
end;
```

If You remove the comment You will get error, because You don't have values in Your arrays with 2 index. The for loop will iterate from the first value of it's attribute(a.first - which is 1 in the example above) and increment it up to the second value of it's attibute(a.last whichi is the 3). So You will have 1,2,3 for the looping indexes and in the second step You will get no data found error for the array.

Comment: Hi @mikron, thanks for your answer. is there any way to reassign the array instead of loop to reset it? thanks.